# Postgres count items by interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the count of items given an interval with no start or stop times specified. I would imagine you could do it with window functions but i am not too sure how to go about it.

The problem is as follows i would like to get the number of times people login to a website within a given an arbitrary interval say 20 mins.

Example A

```
     1. 2015-06-24 23:00:00
     2. 2015-06-24 23:45:00
     3. 2015-06-25 00:00:00
     4. 2015-06-25 00:15:00
     5. 2015-06-25 00:17:00
     6. 2015-06-25 00:21:00
```

In the above example I would highlight items (2,3),(3,4,5), (4,5,6), (5,6) the output I would like is the

```
start,end,count
2015-06-25 23:45:00,2015-06-25 00:00:00,2
2015-06-25 00:00:00,2015-06-25 00:17:00,3
2015-06-25 00:15:00,2015-06-25 00:21:00,3
```

Also only keep the data where count >= 2 otherwise everything will be a valid grouping

Now is a window function the way i should go, cte or is there another practice to adopt?

Comment: Are those windows fixed or floating? If you had `6. 2015-06-25 01:21:00`, how would it change the result?

Comment: if that were the case then the results would be batched (2,3),(3,4,5) I guess the thing I missed was that where the count is >=2 otherwise everything will be caught

Comment: why is 3 going into two groups at once?

Comment: Because it looks at every login time and adds the interval of 20mins and counts how many items fall in between there.
so item 
      1. 1+interval has 1 and count is less then 2 so ignore
      2. 2+interval has two items 2 and 3
      3. 3+ interval has 3, 4,5
      4. 4+interval has 4,5,6
      5. 5+interval has 5,6

Comment: 5+ is not in your resultset, is it intentional?

Comment: Yes just realised that, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query with self join:

```
select a.id, a.log_at, max(b.log_at), count(1)
from logs a
join logs b on b.log_at >= a.log_at and b.log_at <= a.log_at+ '20 m'::interval
group by 1, 2
having count(1) > 1
order by 1
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! It works I am not even going to worry about performance at this moment will work on that on the future.

Comment: If the query is too slow (on large amount of data), first create an index on `log_at`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get each "day" groups with counts by a query like:

```
SELECT MIN(last_seen_at), MAX(last_seen_at), COUNT(*)
FROM user_kinds
GROUP BY DATE(last_seen_at)
ORDER BY DATE(last_seen_at) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Which on my sample data set yields a result like:

```
 2015-06-26 00:12:30.476548 | 2015-06-26 22:06:25.134322 |    69
 2015-06-25 00:46:03.392651 | 2015-06-25 23:49:46.616964 |    14
 2015-06-24 14:22:33.578176 | 2015-06-24 23:39:01.32241  |    10
 2015-06-23 01:42:53.438663 | 2015-06-23 20:12:21.864601 |     2
(5 rows)
```

Comment: if someone logged in at 2015-06-23 23:59:00 and then 2015-06-24 00:10:00 they would show a count of 1 for each day. Even thought they are within my 20 min interval.